# run external program from variable - powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, external

In my config.xml file is:

```
<Settings>
    <Prog>notepad.exe</Prog>
</Settings>
```

in my PS script is:

```
$settings = @{
    Program = $ConfigFile.Settings.Prog
}

#try run it
& $settings.Program
```

> WARNING: The term 'notepad.exe' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

Why this error occurs?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? Your exact code actually does work for me.

Comment: Powershell version 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the absolute path to notepad.exe (ie. C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe) and see if that helps.